# Reset Zoom of Interactive Altair

Tags: python, zooming, altair

I would like to have a way (button for example) to reset the zoom in or zoom out to some start of an interactive plot from `altair`. Here is some reproducible code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
cars = data.cars()

alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
).interactive()
```

Output:

[image]

Sometimes you accidentally zoom in or zoom out to some way like this:

[image]

Is there a way to quickly reset the zoom in `altair`?

Answer (score 0):

You can double click the plot to reset the zoom.